# Reviews about maximum brightness on screen

Tags: android

i change the screen brightness to maximum like this:

```
   WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
                 params.screenBrightness = 1.0f;
                 getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

its work excellent, but the problem is when i go out from my program

the brightness return to original brightness

how to leave the brightness maximum Even when I leave the program

Comment: did you extract it als method and call it also in onresume();?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To persist brightness you need to add `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission in your manifest.xml file

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,       Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 255);
```

and in manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i got error on the word System - System cannot be resolved or is not a field.  why ?

Comment: just press ctrl + shift + o it will import file for it